# add a button in a canvas view in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-view

This is the content of main_activity file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val myCanvasView = MyCanvasView(this)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //R.layout.activity_main
//        val button: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    }
}
```

I created a custom canvas view here is the code

```
class MyCanvasView(context: Context) : View(context) {
    private var path = Path()
    // variable for holding the color to draw with
    private val drawColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorPaint, null)

    // To store the x and y coordinate where the user touched the screen
    private var motionTouchEventX = 0f
    private var motionTouchEventY = 0f

    // the x and y coordinate where the user lifts their finger from the screen
    private var currentX = 0f
    private var currentY = 0f

    private val touchTolerance = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop
    private lateinit var extraCanvas: Canvas
    private lateinit var extraBitmap: Bitmap
```

Now I want to add a button to this view. What changes do I make in the activity_mail.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
        android:text="@string/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        class="MyCanvasView"
        android:layout_width="415dp"
        android:layout_height="488dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText,MissingClass,MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-2dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What changes should I make to the code so that I can display a button along with a particular part of the screen assigned to the canvas view?

Comment: You want to show the button on top of your MyCanvasView? So MyCanvasView is hidden?

Comment: No I want to make two views on 1 screen only, 1 a button and a second view that has my custom view MyCanvasView.

Comment: You want insert Button inside in your customView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConstraintLayout can make one view's constraint on a later defined view. Here is an example to make button and your_view from top to bottom.

```
<Button id="@+id/button"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/your_view"
  />

<YourView id="@+id/your_view"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  />
```